# Can't create unique index in postgres, it says "key is duplicate" even when it's not

Tags: postgresql

I created a unique index for a table and got the following error:

```
SQL error: ERROR: could not create unique index "unique_product" DETAIL: Key (mastercode)=() is duplicated
```

So i run a query to check for duplicated records and really found some duplicates:

```
select * from product p where (select count(*) from product pp where pp.mastercode = p.mastercode) > 1
```

But even after deleting them i could not create the index, it shows the same error and the query to check for duplicates shows nothing.

Looks like it didn't update the indices after deleting the duplicates, or something like that. How can i solve this?

**UPDATE**
Something i forgot to mention but may be important, i already have an index on the field `mastercode`, which is a default index (not unique). Don't know if this has something to do.

Comment: May be a silly question, but... did you remember to commit the deletion?

Comment: Yes, because after running the query to see the duplicates it shows no duplicates.

Comment: If you're running that query from within the same transaction, then that's what you'd see, even if it's uncommitted.

Comment: It's not in the same transaction.

Comment: Also tried vacuum (with default options)

Answer (score 9):

Check the results from this query:

```
SELECT  mastercode, count(*)
FROM product
GROUP BY mastercode
HAVING count(*) > 1; -- not unique
```

Comment: Is there a reason to be a difference between your query and mine, for duplicate check?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you have an instance of a null mastercode, and are trying to insert another null mastercode.

Try `select * from product where mastercode is null;`

Comment: Huh, what? Two `NULL` values aren't equal, and do not conflict in a `UNIQUE` index.

Comment: In sql server you need a filter on your unique index to allow nulls. Is that not true in postgres?

Comment: No, postgres accepts multiple null values for unique fields. But that's not the case anyway, i don't have any records with mastercode = null